# Is it necessary to implements the serialisation, when DTO has json annotation (JsonIgnoreProperties etc)?

Tags: java, json, serialversionuid

What is the role of providing manual serialVersionUID on performance tuning?

**We are using Object mapper to convert java to json and vice versa.**